# Align 2 dropdowns horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem where I need to align several `dropdowns` horizontally. I have tried with pure table tags and it works but I suspect it is bad practice. Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1440c8a6/5/

Here is `HTML` code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

            <div class="pull-left">

                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        Dropdown
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        Dropdown
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="#" role="button">button1</a>
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="#" role="button">button2</a>
            </div>

            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am trying to align dropdowns in left part as buttons in right part:

[image]

I have tried with this structure but not sure if this is good or bad:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first div here</td>
    <td>second div here</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use: **display:inline-block**. Also, add your **html** code to help you with a real answer.

Comment: If your question is about best practices for your working code rather than how to fix broken code, you could give http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ a look.

Comment: @JohnSnow This is about altering the behavior of code, this does not belong on CR.

Comment: The concerns about bad practice is on topic for CR, the broken part is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `display:inline-block` to `.dropdown`

**CSS**

```
.dropdown{
    display: inline-block;   
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/1440c8a6/6/)**

Comment: So simple! Thank you very match. It fixed my problem. Also I have added another class rather then expanding existing.